# constructor doesn't work properly on flutter

Tags: flutter, class, constructor, widget, statefulwidget

I have create a class called Size

- Class name: Size

enter code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/pages/components/font.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Size extends StatefulWidget {
  double font = sizevar.fontSizeRatio;
  double fontH = sizevar.fontSizeRatioH;
  Size();

  @override
  _SizeState createState() => _SizeState();
}

class _SizeState extends State<Size> {
  void initState() {
    sizevar.fontSizeRatio = 25;
    sizevar.fontSizeRatioH = 30;

    super.initState();
  }

  _SizeState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            sizevar.fontSizeRatio = sizevar.fontSizeRatio - 2;
          }),
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline, color: Colors.red),
        ),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  sizevar.fontSizeRatio = sizevar.fontSizeRatio + 2;
                }),
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined, color: Colors.red)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

the above code is used to resize the font of the text daynamically. I want to use it on different other class like a class named SizeCheck.

- class name: SizeCheck

  enter code

```
import 'package:firstapp/pages/components/body.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/pages/components/bodyTitle.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/pages/components/font.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/pages/components/size.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SizeCheck> createState() => SizeCheckState();
}

class SizeCheckState extends State<SizeCheck> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Resize",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: sizevar.fontSizeRatio,
            )),
        **actions: [Size()],**
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              BodyTitle("Title"),
              ContentBody('how we resize the text'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I pressed the button the text size doesn't change immediately
 [img when i press the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwyal.png)
,but when I hot reload the emulator it works.
[img after hot reload the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnRom.png)
I am using flutter v2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what sizevar is, but here is why this issue is happening and how to fix it:

The issue is dead simple, you are updating the value, but you are not telling `SizeCheck` to rebuild itself, to do that, you must call `setState` **from within `SizeCheck`** calling it from Size is not enough.

To fix this, I recommend you add a callback into `Size`, like this:

```
class Size extends StatefulWidget {
  double font = sizevar.fontSizeRatio;
  double fontH = sizevar.fontSizeRatioH;

  VoidCallback? onSizeIncrease;
  VoidCallback? onSizeDecrease;
  
  Size({required this.onSizeIncrease, required this.onSizeDecrease});

  @override
  _SizeState createState() => _SizeState();
}
```

then on `Size`'s state:

```
IconButton(
          onPressed: onSizeDecrease,
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline, color: Colors.red),
        ),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: onSizeIncrease,
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined, color: Colors.red)),
```

This way you can call these on the `SizeCheck` widget:

```
actions: [Size(
  onSizeIncrease: () => setState(() {
            sizevar.fontSizeRatio = sizevar.fontSizeRatio + 2;
          }),
  onSizeDecrease: () => setState(() {
            sizevar.fontSizeRatio = sizevar.fontSizeRatio - 2;
          }),
)]
```

Comment: thank you it works without VoidCallback.                                        sizevar is a class  name that have static variable.                        sizevar {
  static double fontSizeRatio = 22;
  static double fontSizeRatioH = 29;
}